# Isomorphism on stalk implies local isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of finite type of schemes over a field $k$. Assume that there exists $x \in X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to f_* \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ is an isomorphism. Is it true that there exist open subschemes $f(x) \in U \subset Y$ and $x \in V \subset X$ such that $f{|_V}: V \to U$ is an isomorphism? Could we drop the finiteness condition?

Probably, a natural generalization is the following: assume that $(R_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(S_j)_{j \in J}$ are directed systems. Suppose that we have maps $R_i \to colim(S_j)$ and for every $i \in I$ there exists $j \in J$ and the map $R_i \to S_j$ compatible with the map $q: colim(R_i) \to colim(S_j)$. Assume the $q$ is an isomorphism. Is it true that there exists a pair of indices $i, j$ such that $R_i \to S_j$ is an isomorphism? If no, what conditions one should impose to make it true?

Comment: For your generalization, I think it’s no. Consider, for positive $i$, $R_i=k[x_0,\ldots,x_{2i}]$ and $S_i=k[x_0,\ldots,x_{2i+1}]$. For the original question, you would need to clarify what you mean by $f_*\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ (where are the parentheses?!). If that’s just $f^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ being an isomorphism, then the statement is true.

Comment: Your hypothesis looks strange. Do you mean to assume $O_{Y, f (x)} \to O_{X, x}$, or equivalently, $(f^* O_Y)_x \to O_{X, x}$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Your first question is essentially Hartshorne I.4.7, which has been dealt with [on MSE before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871244/problem-i-4-7-in-hartshorne). The idea is that we can lift the isomorphism to an isomorphism on an affine open neighborhood by inverting at most one element in each of $k[V]$ and $k[U]$. The finiteness condition cannot be dropped: consider Spec of $k[t]\to k[t]_{(t)}$. Any open subscheme of the source is finite type over $k$, while no open subscheme of the target is.